# What is some smooth parameterization of $y - |x| = 0$?

Tags: derivatives, parametrization

Apparently, $\{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2, y - |x| = 0\}$ is an example of a level curve $C: f(x,y) = c$, such that $f$ is not smooth, but $C$ admits a smooth parameterization.

What is some smooth parameterization of the the level curve $C: y - |x| = 0$?

I am not sure how such a construction is possible. We would like to have $\gamma: (\alpha, \beta) \subset \Bbb R \to \Bbb R^2$, such $\gamma(t) = (\gamma_1(t), \gamma_2(t))$ satisfies $\gamma_2(t) = |\gamma_1(t)|$, for all $t \in (\alpha, \beta)$. If $\gamma_1(t) \neq 0$ for all $t$, then $\gamma$ doesn't cover $C$. On the other hand, if $\gamma_1(t) = 0$ for some $t$, then $\gamma_2$ cannot be differentiable at this point. Am I missing something here?

**Edit:**

Where a function $f$ is said to be "smooth" if it is $C^{\infty}$

Comment: $$\gamma(t)=\left(t\cdot\exp((t^4-1)/t^2),|t|\cdot\exp((t^4-1)/t^2)\right)$$

Comment: @Did is there a place where I can see a proof that $t \mapsto |t|e^{t^2 - 1/t^2}$ is $C^{\infty}$?

Comment: Not that I am aware of--but you might realize that the only problematic point is $t=0$ and that the $e^{-1/t^2}$ term makes that there is no problem there. In the end, the tool to apply is that $|t|^ae^{-1/t^2}\to0$ when $t\to0$, for every $a$.

Comment: Why do you think this is possible? And what do you understand under parametrization? Like paramatrization of a manifold where it is the inverse of a chart? Because then it would have to be regular.

Comment: Most differential topology books contains proofs of smoothness of functions like that. One key word to look for is *smooth [bump function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function)*.

Answer (score 4):

Reparametrize by $t^3$, that is, consider $\gamma(t) = (t^3, |t^3|)$. The issue is that this parametrization is smooth, but not regular, that is, we must have $\gamma'(t) = 0$ for some $t$ (note that $t=0$ does it, as expected).

We will never find a parametrization both smooth *and* regular.

Comment: But $t \mapsto |t^3|$ is not smooth, is it?

Comment: Ah, some people use "smooth" meaning only $C^1$. We have that $|t^3|$ is only $C^2$ in all of $\Bbb R$, thing mess up at the third derivative ($f'''(0)$ does not exist)

Comment: Smooth here means $C^{\infty}$. But thank you for the example because I never really paid attention to the fact that $|t^3|$ is $C^2$.

Comment: Neither did I, I actually got some paper to do the calculation here. I'm not sure if there is a $C^\infty$ parametrization, though. If I come up with something I'll add it here.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's a liiittle too late, but I think I found a solution so I'll post it anyway.

The smooth parametrization is $$\gamma(t)=\left(e^{-\frac{1}{t^2}}\cdot t,\: e^{-\frac{1}{t^2}}\cdot |t|\right), \quad \gamma(0) = 0.$$

It's image is clearly all of $\{(x, y) \:\mid\: y = |x|\}$. It is obviously smooth everywhere except $t=0$, and at the only "problematic" point $t = 0$ all one-sided derivatives will exist and will be equal to zero, thus all derivatives are defined and are continuous, proving $\gamma$ to be $C^\infty$.