# Why do we need a chart of a submanifold to be an immersion?

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry

I'm now working on Amann's *analysis II*. In VII.9 (page 253 in the English version), it defines the chart of a submanifold as follows:

> The map $\varphi$ is called an $m$-dimensional (local) $C^q$ chart of $M$ around $p$ if:
>
> 1. $U:=\mathrm{dom}(\varphi)$ is an open neighborhood of $p$ in $M$
> 2. $\varphi$ is a homeomorphism of $U$ onto the open set $V:=\varphi(U)$ of $\mathbb{R}^m$
> 3. $g:=i_M\circ\varphi^{-1}$ is a $C^q$ immersion.
>
> Where $i_M:M\to\mathbb{R}^n,x\mapsto x$ is the canonical injection of $M$ into $\mathbb{R}^n$.

My problem is why we need the third requirement which makes $i_M\circ\varphi^{-1}$ an immersion. What will go wrong if we drop it? Besides, why don't we require $\varphi^{-1}$ an immersion directly but $i_M\circ\varphi^{-1}$ ? I don't see the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The immersion condition in (3) is a sort of niceness condition. Immersions help to rule out "corners" in manifolds. Intuitively, we don't want the curve $\{y = |x|\} \subset \mathbb R^2$ to be a smooth manifold since it has a sharp corner at $x = 0$ and no well-defined tangent space at that point. It turns out that $i_M \circ \varphi^{-1}$ being $C^q$ is not enough to prevent this from happening - as shown in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1675769/what-is-some-smooth-parameterization-of-y-x-0), one can even take the parameterization to be $C^\infty$!

However, I claim that any such parameterization will not be an immersion at $x = 0$. Suppose $\alpha = (\alpha_1,\alpha_2): \mathbb R \to U \subset \mathbb R^2$ is a smooth parameterization (the inverse of what your book defines to be a chart) of $U \subset \{y = |x|\}$ with the point $(0,0) \in U$. By translation, I can assume $\alpha(0) = (0,0)$. Then, $\alpha$ is an immersion at $0$ iff $\alpha'(0) = (\alpha_1'(0), \alpha_2'(0)) \neq 0$.  One can compute that $\lim_{t \to 0^-} \alpha'(t)  = (v,-v)$ for some $v \geq 0$ and $\lim_{t \to 0^+} \alpha'(t) = (w, w)$ for some $w \geq 0$. Since $(v,-v) = (w,w)$ by smoothness, this implies that $v = w= 0$, hence $\alpha$ cannot be an immersion.

As for your second question, I think your book probably hasn't defined yet what it means for $\varphi^{-1}:\mathbb R^m \to M$ (a map into a manifold, not Euclidean space!) to be an immersion yet (but correct me if I'm wrong). This requires some notion of a tangent space, which wouldn't make sense to define before the definition of a manifold. Still, once you have a definition for such an immersion, it is true that $\varphi^{-1}$ is an immersion.

Comment: That's what I want! Thx a lot~